# Is it appropriate to give demo user info to the iOS application review team on production environment?

Tags: ios, iphone

Today they rejected my app and wanted demo user info to log in and manually test the app. I don't want to create a demo user on prod environment and give permission to make silly actions of testers. All users are connected to each other and the tester actions will be seen by other users. How can I manage this and what was your strategy for this kind of situation?

**Addition:** I don't want to write additional code and test it for a successful iPhone review. It doesn't make sense. We have a **test** environment. How can I use this environment for review purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we sometimes do is that we implement a test user whose actions get wiped out/deleted after a pre-determined amount of time (1 hour, 1 day, depending on the sensitivity of the environment).

Comment: all these are make no sense. I want to ask another question. Is it appropiate to write additional code and test it for a successful iphone review?

Comment: You mean write code tailored just for the review process? That's probably not a great idea.  How do you guys normally test the app on production if you don't have the ability to create test users?

Comment: we have a testing environment. different rest endpoint, app server, db etc..

Comment: i give up. i will create a **test account** on **production** environment and countinue to hate apple.

Comment: @hgoz If you hate Apple then why are you developing for their platform?

Comment: @JohnTopley my web app should have clients on mobile. this is why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way round their request.  It's something of a black box, but I don't think they have the time to do much more than test the normal functionality that users would expect plus a few edge cases (how the app reacts to phone calls, etc.) so I'm not sure what you are expecting to see.  Your best bet if you don't want to change any code would seem to be to set your release date to manual (rather than the app being released as soon as they have completed the review) and then to reset your production server before confirming release.  No other users will be able to download the app and interact with it until it has been released.  You may still have to provide a test account for updates though.

Comment: ok. i will set the release date to manual. However this is a web app which is currently on production, if test account makes actions. it will be seen by other users. Ok i give up. i will create a test account..

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1) Make a special account that will not save its changes to the server

2) Don't publish the app on the app store

Comment: 'special account' option needs work on both server and client sides. this means another tests for *testing purposes*. other is not an option at all.